# sed: How to remove the first blank line after a pattern match

Tags: sed

I would like to remove the first blank line after a pattern match in a file using sed.

For example, if I were trying to match the below file on b:

```html
a

b
c

d
```

the would result would be:

```html
a

b
c
d
```

I've tried variations of the following: `sed -i '/b/,/^$/{//d}' FILE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest with GNU sed:

```
sed -i '/b/,/^$/{ /^$/d }' file
```

Output:

```
a

b
c
d
```

Comment: You were already very close to the solution with your attempt. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/b/{:a;n;/^$/d;ba}' file
```

Locate `b`, then print/fetch lines until an empty line and delete it.

Comment: Would be great to have an explanation of :a, n and ba.

Comment: Is there some link to this material you find particularly good?

Comment: @john-jones try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info) in particular [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Branching-and-flow-control)